# SWIG typemap with C++ overloaded function

Tags: c++, overloading, swig

I have a function definition like so:

void Foo(int szData,int Data[]);

and I have a SWIG typemap like so:

```
%typemap(in) (int szData,int Data[])
{
  int i; 
  if (!PyTuple_Check($input))
  {
      PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,"Expecting a tuple for this parameter");
      $1 = 0;
  }
  else
    $1 = PyTuple_Size($input);
  $2 = (int *) malloc(($1+1)*sizeof(int));
  for (i =0; i < $1; i++)
  {
      PyObject *o = PyTuple_GetItem($input,i);
      if (!PyInt_Check(o))
      {
         free ($2);
         PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError,"Expecting a tuple of integers");
         return NULL;
      }
      $2[i] = PyInt_AsLong(o);
  }
  $2[i] = 0;
}
```

The typemap allows me to call Foo() from Python like so:
Foo((1,2,3))

This works perfectly well until I add an overloaded function, such as:
int Foo(double t);

Everything builds fine, but now when I call Foo() from Python I get:

```
NotImplementedError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'Foo'.
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    Foo(int,int [])
    Foo(double)
```

If I remove the typemap(in) then it works OK as well.

Appreciate if anyone has any ideas as I am totally stumped...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rename the typemapped function in the SWIG interface file.  SWIG does support polymorphism, but it has a problem matching a tuple to a C type.  Here's my interface:

```
%module demo

%begin %{
#pragma warning(disable:4127 4100 4211 4706)
%}

%{
#include <iostream>
void Foo(int size, int data[]) { std::cout << __FUNCSIG__ << std::endl; }
void Foo(double d)             { std::cout << __FUNCSIG__ << std::endl; }
void Foo(int a,int b)          { std::cout << __FUNCSIG__ << std::endl; }
void Foo(int a)                { std::cout << __FUNCSIG__ << std::endl; }
%}

%typemap(in) (int szData,int Data[])
{
  int i; 
  if (!PyTuple_Check($input))
  {
      PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,"Expecting a tuple for this parameter");
      $1 = 0;
  }
  else
    $1 = (int)PyTuple_Size($input);
  $2 = (int *) malloc(($1+1)*sizeof(int));
  for (i =0; i < $1; i++)
  {
      PyObject *o = PyTuple_GetItem($input,i);
      if (!PyInt_Check(o))
      {
         free ($2);
         PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError,"Expecting a tuple of integers");
         return NULL;
      }
      $2[i] = PyInt_AsLong(o);
  }
  $2[i] = 0;
}

void Foo(int a, int b);
void Foo(double d);
void Foo(int a);
%rename Foo Foot;
void Foo(int szData,int Data[]);
```

My build and test with Visual Studio 2012:

```
C:\Demo>swig -c++ -python demo.i && cl /nologo /LD /W4 /EHsc demo_wrap.cxx /Fe_demo.pyd /Ic:\python33\include -link /LIBPATH:c:\python33\libs && python -i demo.py
demo_wrap.cxx
   Creating library _demo.lib and object _demo.exp
>>> Foo(1)
void __cdecl Foo(int)
>>> Foo(1,1)
void __cdecl Foo(int,int)
>>> Foo(1.5)
void __cdecl Foo(double)
>>> Foot((1,2,3))
void __cdecl Foo(int,int [])
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response. If I rename the function to 'Foot()' as you suggest, this would mean that the user would be calling a different function name, depending on the input parameter i.e. not Foo() when a tuple is supplied. Ideally I needed to have this function overloaded....if possible.

Comment: See section [6.15](http://swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIGPlus_overloaded_methods) in the swig docs.  One quote: "Regrettably, SWIG is not able to support every possible use of valid C++ overloading." Changing the order the functions are declared might help, but otherwise I don't see another option.

Comment: You could still wrap the function in Python, do an `isinstance(tuple)` on the parameter, and call the renamed function in that instance to make it transparent to the user.

Comment: I think I will live within the limits of SWIG polymorphism in future.Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Just for all the people finding this while searching for the error message: Typemaps with typecheck can help here, see http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Typemaps.html#Typemaps_overloading

Answer (score 1):

Extending the answer from Mark Tolonen.

You could add to your `demo.i` file:

```
%insert("python") %{
FooOld = Foo
def Foo(arg):
  if (isinstance(arg,tuple)):
    return Foot(arg)
  else:
    return FooOld(arg)
%}
```

and you get the polymorphism with unchanged names